# Twilio WhatsApp bug

Tags: python-3.x, twilio, whatsapp

I am getting this unexpected error with no explanation regarding Twilio API for WhatsApp messaging:-

```
print("Please enter a message.")
body_of_the_message = input()
account_sid = mysid
auth_token = myauthtoken
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token) 
message = client.messages.create(from_='whatsapp:mytwilionum', body=(body_of_the_message),to='whatsapp:+myphone' )
sid = message.sid
print(f"The message SID is:- {sid}")
```

When I run this, I pass in “Hi there.” for the input.

This is what I get in response:-

```
The message SID is:- (sid)
```

I don’t see any notifications for the message being sent, and even when I check the chat history. Please help me with this stuff.

Comment: Check the Debugger - https://www.twilio.com/console/debugger?quickDate=72

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Are you using the WhatsApp sandbox? And have you connected your WhatsApp number by sending the message with the join phrase? And are you trying to send outbound messages within a conversation?

Comment: I am connected to my sandbox, there is no response except for the message SID when the message is supposed to be sent. I have used the join phrase, also. I am not sending them in a conversation, but a new message.